# Having multiple buttons in cell that pass selected buttons set data to cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, if-statement, uibutton

I have three buttons in my cell that have a price and weight label, what im trying to do is have the selected optionBtn pass the weight and price data to the CartVC

the code that I currently have in the in the CartCell does not yet post the data for the selected optionBtn's weight and price labels

the function `func configure` that I have set in the CartCell works in presenting data in the cells for the CartVC

Where the cart does show the name, category, & image when the atcBtn is pressed to pass the data to the CartVC

What I want is to show the selected optionBtn price and weight (when selected) in the the CartVC cells how would I be able to modify the code I have set for the optionBtns in the func

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage
import Firebase

class Cell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var items: Items!    
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var category: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!   
    @IBOutlet weak var weightOne: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightTwo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightThree: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceOne: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceTwo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceThree: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var addToCart: RoundButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var optionBtn1: RoundButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionBtn2: RoundButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionBtn3: RoundButton!

    var addActionHandler: (() -> Void)?

    func configure(withItems items: Items) {
        name.text = items.name
        category.text = items.category
        image.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: items.image))
        priceOne.text = items.price1
        priceTwo.text = items.price2
        priceThree.text = items.price3
        weightOne.text = items.weight1
        weightTwo.text = items.weight2
        weightThree.text = items.weight3
    }
    @IBAction func atcBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.addActionHandler?()
    }   
}
```

---

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var cartButton: BarButtonItem!!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var itemSetup: [Items] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return itemSetup.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? Cell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        let item = itemSetup[indexPath.row]
        cell.configure(withItem: item)
        cell.addActionHandler = {
             Cart.currentCart.items.append(item)
        }
        return cell
    }

}
```

---

```
class CartViewController: UIViewController {

    var items: Items!
    @IBOutlet weak var cartTableView: UITableView!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        cartTableView.dataSource = self
        cartTableView.delegate = self
    }

}

extension CartViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Cart.currentCart.cartItems.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartCell", for: indexPath) as! CartCell

        let cart = Tray.currentCart.cartItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.configure(withItems: cart)

        return cell
    }
}
```

---

```
class CartCell: UITableViewCell {

    var selctedBtn: Cell?

    @IBOutlet weak var lblMealName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageUrl: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblSubTotal: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblWeight: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    var lastSelectedButton = UIButton()
    func configure(withItems items: Items) {
        // lblWeight.text = "\(items.weight1)"
        // lblSubTotal.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: items.price1)!)"
        lblMealName.text = "\(items.category): \(items.name)"
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        imageUrl.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: items.imageUrl))

        // optionBtns I dont know how to set the code to where I can individual
        //  select a btn to pass the data to the cell
        if selctedBtn?.optionBtn1.isSelected == true {
            lblSubTotal.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: items.price1)!)"
            lblWeight.text = "\(items.weight1)"            

        } else if selctedBtn?.optionBtn2.isSelected == true {
            lblSubTotal.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: items.price2)!)"
            lblWeight.text = "\(items.weight2)"

        } else if selctedBtn?.optionBtn3.isSelected == true {
            lblSubTotal.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: items.price3)!)"
            lblWeight.text = "\(items.weight3)"

        }

       // or this

       switch lastSelectedButton {
    case selctedBtn!.optionBtn1:
        isSelected = true
        lblSubTotal.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: items.price1)!)"
        lblWeight.text = "\(items.weight1)"
    case selctedBtn!.optionBtn2:
        isSelected = true
        lblSubTotal.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: items.price2)!)"
        lblWeight.text = "\(items.weight2)"
    case selctedBtn!.optionBtn3:
        isSelected = true
        lblSubTotal.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: items.price3)!)"
        lblWeight.text = "\(items.weight3)"
    default:
        break
    }
    }  

 // still running tests to make this work just can't seem to have the selected buttons data pass to the Cart Cells
}
```

Update:

just added some code that I have been testing still no luck in how to pass the label to the  cart after the option button is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass back values in closures.

So, in your `Cell` class (naming is confusing to discuss - make it something like `SelectItemCell`), you could change your closure var to:

```
var addActionHandler: ((Int) -> Void)?
```

Then, in your `addToCart` button action, something along these lines:

```
@IBAction func atcBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // pass back the user selected values
    var i = 0
    switch lastSelectedButton {
    case optionBtn1:
        i = 1
    case optionBtn2:
        i = 2
    default:
        i = 3
    }
    self.addActionHandler?(i)

}
```

That's rather awkward, and presumably you will be tracking actual values, but for example purposes this will work.

Now, in your VC that holds that table, in `cellForRowAt`, instead of your current:

```
    cell.addActionHandler = {
         Cart.currentCart.items.append(item)
    }
```

assign the closure like this:

```
    cell.addActionHandler = { (option: Int) in
        print("Option selected = \(option)")
        // do something based on the option that was selected
        // maybe item.selectedOption = option
        Cart.currentCart.items.append(item)
    }
```

If you want to pass back more than one value, add parameters:

```
var addActionHandler: ((Int, Int) -> Void)?
```

and in your button action:

```
self.addActionHandler?(priceVal, weightVal)
```

and your closure becomes:

```
    cell.addActionHandler = { (price: Int, weight: Int) in
        // use price and weight vars
        // ...
    }
```

---

**Edit**

If you don't already have a `.selectedOption` property of your `Items` class, you should add one (of type Int). You can use that to track the user's selection.

Change your `cellForRowAt` func along these lines:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? Cell else { return UITableViewCell() }

    // use var to make item mutable
    var item = itemSetup[indexPath.row]

    // pass item to cell to configure labels / buttons / etc
    cell.configure(withItem: item)

    // when the "add to cart" button in the cell is tapped
    cell.addActionHandler = { (option: Int) in

    // option will be 1, 2 or 3, indicating which button the user tapped
    print("Option selected = \(option)")

        // update the .selected property of your data
        item.selectedOption = option

        Cart.currentCart.items.append(item)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Now, in your `CartCell` in your `CartViewController`, you can fill in the labels like this:

```
    if items.selectedOption == 1 {
        lblSubTotal.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: items.price1)!)"
        lblWeight.text = "\(items.weight1)"            

    } else if items.selectedOption == 2 {
        lblSubTotal.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: items.price2)!)"
        lblWeight.text = "\(items.weight2)"

    } else if items.selectedOption == 3 {
        lblSubTotal.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: items.price3)!)"
        lblWeight.text = "\(items.weight3)"

    }
```

Comment: I just ran the code for the first half of your answer, I can't seem to figure out how to pass the of the weight and price (the weight labels are String Values and the Price Labels are integer values in their Items Class) , since I am trying to have multiple values to the CartVC price & weight through optionBtns which pass 1,2, or 3 for price and weight depending one the button selected

Comment: @Evelyn - do you have a property of your `Items` object to hold the currently selected "Option"? Such as: you have `.price1` `.price2` `.price3` and `.weight1` `.weight2` `.weight3` ... which correspond to selected "option" button 1, 2 or 3... so do you also have a `.selectedOption` property?

Comment: no I did not have a selectedOption property in my Items class but I just put it in, the code works now. nut all do you mean by your question? can you break it down Gumby style for me I'm a bit of a slow learner lol